# How do I remove the flat parts that are not part of the function in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

```
GraphicsRow[
 {Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> Automatic], 
  Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {0, 30}}],
  Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
   PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {0, 30}}]}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

yields

[image]

How do I get the full "bowl" look without the extra flat part filling out the plane at $z=30$? I must be missing something simple...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14102/5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `ClippingStyle` option to control the appearance of the cut off part.

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {0, 30}}, ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]