# Difference between surface plot in mathematica and matlab

Tags: plotting

Why Mathematica surface plot is showing gray color in the lower region on the surface plot. But when I cross-checked with Matlab it is not showing any thing like that. I used `ListPlot3D[data1, 
 AxesLabel -> {"k1","k2","L"}]` function for plotting the surface plot in mathematica.

[image: difference in mathematica and matlab]

Comment: The system is automatically choosing a plot range (the spread in the z axis), but here is not doing a great job.  Try adding the option `PlotRange -> All` to your plot command.

Comment: Try `PlotRange -> All` or `ClippingStyle -> None`.  They give different results. You probably want the first. The second suggestion might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Use an explicit `PlotRange` or `PlotRange->All` in *Mathematica*.  The "L" axis in *Mathematica* only goes down to around 5.3 whereas the Matlab goes down much farther.  The bigger question is what kind of color scheme does Matlab use?

Comment: @JimB : I believe that Matlab scheme is called "Hideous"...

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18025/how-do-i-remove-the-flat-parts-that-are-not-part-of-the-function-in-plot3d

Comment: @Jim, that's MATLAB's (relatively) new color scheme `parula()`, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161647).

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, but this is the first time I think you're wrong.  ciao is clearly correct.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I now see what you mean. ;)